# Как выдать ошибку при запуске бота на Go, если MySQL выключен?

Tags: golang

```
func Start() {
    dbpool, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/sn")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer dbpool.Close()
    ...
}
```

Функция Start вызывается в главном main.go, база данных выключена, но скрипт вызовет ошибку, только если будет отправлен запрос сервер (/method/users.get и др.). Мне нужно проверять наличие ошибки при запуске, а не в каждом методе API.

Comment: вместо `log.Fatal(err)` возвращать ошибку навверх

Comment: В смысле возвращать наверх?

Comment: вместо `log.Fatal(err)` написать `return err`

Comment: too many arguments to return
        have (error)
        want ()

Comment: потому что функция не возвращает ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. модифицировать функцию,, чтобы она возвращала ошибку:

```go
func Start() error {
    dbpool, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/sn")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer dbpool.Close()
    /* ... */
}

func main() {
    err := Start()
    if err != nil {
        // обработка
    }
}
```

Этот вариант является общепринятым и рекомендован разработчиками языка

2. использовать в `main()` конструкцию `recover()` и заменить log.Fatal() на panic():

```go
func main() {
    defer func() {
        if e := recover(); e != nil {
            // обработка
        }
    }()
    Start()
 }
```

Учтите, что вызов `panic` является крайней мерой при обработке ошибок в Go; он **при**останавливает весь рантайм. Также обратите внимание, что `log.Fatal` под капотом использует не `panic`, который "мягко" останавливает функции, как `return`, а `os.Exit`, "грубо" останавливающий весь runtime. Поэтому требуется заменить в таком случае этот метод на `panic`